# How to create .war file in liferay 7 with gradle?

Tags: gradle, liferay, war

I am developing liferay7 application with gradle and eclipse editor. Now I want to generate .war file for tomcat. How can I create .war file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply plugin: 'war'` should be all you need.

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

Comment: Not all its need to create project in /workspace/wars dir (If you place it in /modules it will be not recognized from workspace plugin and will be not added to gradle projects)

Answer (score 0):

For Liferay 7 I think we should use .jar files as stated [here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-modules-with-blade-cli) :

> Once you finish developing your project, you can use Gradle to build
>   your project’s **JAR file** and use Blade CLI to deploy your module to
>   Liferay Portal’s module framework.